# Adjusting WordPress site git repository location

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, github

I have a git repository containing a WordPress site, the root folder looks like so:

```
/wp-admin
/wp-content
/wp-includes
index.php
license.txt
readme.html
wp-activate.php
wp-blog-header.php
wp-comments-post.php
wp-config-sample.php
wp-cron.php
wp-links-opml.php
wp-load.php
wp-login.php
wp-mail.php
wp-settings.php
wp-signup.php
wp-trackback.php
xmlrpc.php
```

However, the theme folder located in `/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/` is the only folder I need version controlled within this git repository. I'd like the root folder of this repository to instead show the contents of this theme folder only.

However:

- I don't want to loose any commit history
- I want to keep the files as they are, and just change the location of the git repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `git` does not track files, so much as content, you are save to move stuff around:

```
git rm *php license.txt readme.html /wp-admin /wp-includes -r
git mv /wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/* .
git rm /wp-content/ -r
git commit
```

This is all. You'll see that your history remains, yet your root is now the theme.

The nice thing about git, is that your repository is self-contained. So, if you want to try this first, without the risk of breaking something beyond your git-skills, you can simply `cp /path/to/project/root /backup/project` and play around in `/backup/project`. Obviously you should be careful not to push changes from there. Another, more git-full way is to create a  branch and play around in that branch, but my experience is, that people less familiar with Git, have a harder way of managing this, then a "sandbox-copy".

Besides the `git` part, you mention, you want to keep the rest of the structure in place. To do that:

Make a backup (inside your project, before anything else):

```
git archive HEAD > /tmp/my_project.tar
```

Now run the git stuff as mentioned above, i.e. making your git-repo contain only your theme.

Then, extract the archive and place your theme-only repo in there:

```
cd ..
mv <project-name>/ <theme_name>/ #your repo is now in a folder after the name of the theme
mkdir <project-name>/
tar -xf /tmp/my_project.tar <project-name>/ #extract the backup in the project-name folder.
rm -rf <project-name>/wp-content/themes/<theme-name>/ #remove the old theme
mv <theme-name>/ <project-name>/wp-content/themes/ # and move the git-repo with the theme in place of the old theme.
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like your commands will physically move the files, won't this break requirement #2? Also am I correct in thinking each file will need to be listed separately i.e. `license.txt readme.html` etc.

Comment: This will, indeed break #2, but there is really no way to do this elsewise. The files in git are separate from the files on disk. How to get files on disk, correctly, has nothing to do with git, vcs and whatnot, just with copying the correct stuff around.